# Why isn't my top bar image above all other elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a website with a top image and footer image. The footer image is above every element but the top image isn't. Here you have it's code.

```
.header {
  top: 0px;
  background-image: url('http://oi57.tinypic.com/2me730z.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `z-index` to the `.header` class:

```
.header {
    top: 0;
    background-image: url('http://oi57.tinypic.com/2me730z.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index:

```
.header {
top: 0px;
background-image: url('http://oi57.tinypic.com/2me730z.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
position:absolute;
z-index:10
}
```